# For molecular orbital, LCAO approximation is trusty?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, tight-binding

I'm curious how the LCAO approximation is trusty.

I'm majoring in physics and usually treat solid using
tight binding method. Using tight binding method, We can think the periodic molecular orbital as a linear sum of atomic orbitals.

However, LCAO doesn't treat periodic and plain wave condition. As i know they treat the molecular orbital as a linear sum of atomic orbitals.
ex) In "Principles of Electronic Materials and Device", some example approximate H2 molecular orbital with LCAO. Since the H2 molecular has no periodic potential, I think the linear sum of atomic orbitals is not valide from the point of tight binding method.

Why the LCAO is valid? and How the LCAO is trusty?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think LCAO is not valid, particularly for the case of constructing molecular bonds from a sum of atomic orbitals? Is LCAO the exact same set of approximations as tight binding? Well, no, but that doesn't mean that one is right and one is wrong - they just do better under different circumstances.  I'll note that I believe your question shows very little research effort on your part.